# Finding a screenshot with pyautogui in python

Tags: python, python-tesseract

So I want to make a program and in it will be a function that takes a screenshot, then takes the text from the screenshot and types it. I got no clue how any of this works, and I can't get tesseract to find my image. This is my code.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import time
import os
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
import pyautogui 
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract

keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(2)
#words = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
#for i in words:
    #keyboard.press(i)
    #keyboard.release(i)
    #time.sleep(0.01)

#Takes a screenshot. You can pass a four-integer tuple of the left, top, width, and height of the region.
image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,400, 800, 100)) 
#Saves to disk
image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image),cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) 
cv2.imwrite("image1.png", image) 
#Define path to tessaract.exe
path_to_tesseract = image

#Define path to image
path_to_image = ''

#Point tessaract_cmd to tessaract.exe
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

#Open image with PIL
img = Image.open(path_to_image)

#Extract text from image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? And if so, can you copy and paste it to your question? It's unknown if the problem is with your program crashing or just not recognizing the text.